# Pygame is not working while in a Virtual Enviroment

Tags: python, pygame, python-venv

I am trying to use pygame inside of a virtual environment so I don't have to install it on every computer I work on(I go to a school that has a few computer labs). It's installed and I can see it in the venv/lib folder but when I activate it and when I try to import it says that there is no module

Comment: Please add a capture of your session

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new and I don't know what that means or how to do it.

Comment: A common cause of this kind of thing is mismatched python versions. Have you double checked that you haven't installed pygame for python 3 where you're using python 2 etc?

Comment: Trying running `which python` in the terminal to make sure you are pointed at your virtualenv. Also, note that if you normally type `python3` to run python3, but you set up a virtualenv, often times you will actually now type `python` to run that virtualenv's python

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I don't know what happened but just fiddling around with it made it work.